# How does map from Page from Spring data works?

Tags: java, spring, pagination

As the title says how does the [map](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) from org.springframework.data.domain.Page work?

As per the documentation, it suggests that you put a converter as a map parameter, and you get a new map with the converted contents. As per this interpretation, I wrote code to something as follows.

```
Page<T> results = getPagedResults();
return results.map(x -> {
  x.setElement("some constant");
  return x;
});
```

However the above did not work as expected. I got the Page with all the other values intact like count and so on, but the content was an empty list! I actually had to write code this way.

```
Page<T> results = getPagedResults();
return new Page<T>() {
  @Override
  public int getTotalPages() {
    return results.getTotalPages();
  }

  ...

  @Override
  public List<T> getContent() {
    List<T> contents = result.getContent();
    for (T content : contents) {
      content.setElement("some constant");
    }
    return contents;
  }

  ...
};
```

The second choice is verbose and seems to do redundant work. I would have expected the first piece of code to do the same, but it did not.

Am I reading the documentation wrong? And where would you use the map function of Page if it is not supposed to be used, the way I was using it?

Comment: if content of page is empty `content:[]` then `.map(...)` will not work

Comment: The content is not, I actually check for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map the same way as we do:

```
results.map(mapper::convert)
```

where the convert is the method of mapper to convert database entity to DTO or any another object.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a real converter like below:

```
        Page<T> results = getPagedResults();
        Page<T> convertedResults = results.map(new Converter<T, T>() {
            @Override
            public T convert(T page) {
                Page page2 = new Page();
                page2.setElement('some constant');
                //set other fields

                return page2;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I did try that and did not work. Also, `Converter` is sort of `Functional` interface, so you can rewrite it as a lambda without loss of functionality.

Comment: I see, maybe it's expecting new object to be created. see my new solution

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. I am not sure if the updated response will work, because even then you will have a new page and you would lose the properties of the one that you are converting. Also, you still have to get the contents of the page and go over them to reset them anyway. It is not the one-shot answer I was searching for.

Comment: I like this idea and I have to add addition filter for paged  list by some convertion.
This filter is very complex and use additional calculated fields not directly connected to database fields.
Can somebody point to any workig code example of the Page conversion?